# How to show complete document in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

In eclipse, you can put your cursor on a method or a class to show its document. However, in Visual Studio, it only shows the summary, without the parameter info and return value type. And pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to see the parameter info is so annoying! Is there a way that I can make VS show the complete document just like pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and seeing the definition? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you searching but you can activate the `Code Definition Window` via `Menu -> View -> Code Definition Windows`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great! This is the closest solution! Thank you, my friend!

Comment: Thanks for feedback and upvote (+1 for that and nice question) would be nice if you can accept answer if noting better occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visual Studio 2013, you can use the new **Peek Definition** feature by hitting <kbd>Alt+F12</kbd>.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn160178.aspx